# Issue: [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The “listener” argument must be of type function. Received an instance of Object

Tags: node.js

favoriteFunction.js:

```
function favoriteFunction () {
  console.log("the best");
};

module.exports = {
  favoriteFunction,
};
```

app.js:

```
const xmlrpc = require('xmlrpc');
const favoriteFunction = require("./favoriteFunction");

const server = xmlrpc.createServer(options);
server.on('callMyFavoriteFunction', favoriteFunction);
```

The error was thrown on this last line of app.js.

Answer (score 0):

If a function is exported via module.exports:

```
module.exports = {
  favoriteFunction,
}
```

then it can be imported thus:

`const { favoriteFunction } = require("./favoriteFunction");`

rather than

`const favoriteFunction = require("./favoriteFunction");`

module.exports is an object, not a function. However, inside that object is your favoriteFunction after [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)